# Remote Git repo is out of sync with local repo

Tags: git, github

I've noticed my remote repo contains many files which have been long deleted from my local repo. How do I correct this syncing issue?

I've attempted the following to correct:

1. `git add --all`, then pushed. It did not work. Old files remain on remote repo.
2. Created a new branch using `git branch my-new-branch`, then pushed. It did not work. The old files, which are not available locally, still pushed to new branch.
3. Updated `.gitignore` to include `.env` file, then pushed. It did not work. The `.gitignore` file updates, although the `.env` file still exist on remote repo.

If I create a new file, push to remote, delete locally, then push again, the file will be deleted remotely. For some reason this seems to only be occurring with older files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove git cache

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

then push back to the remote

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am 'Removed files from the index (now ignored)'
$ git push
```

edit: to remove remote files, pull the changes from the server, do a git rm on your local repo, commit the changes, and push to the server. The files will be deleted. Don't forget to check whether you have duplicate folder or not.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This worked for the `.env` file found in the .gitignore, but not for the older deleted files which are no longer on my local system.

Comment: Disregard the latter issue. I've tracked the problem. I had a duplicate folder name with the old files residing somewhere else within the folder structure. Again, thank you for your help.